# Class which shows relationship of members in a family

Tags: data-structures

I want to create a **class** which can dynamically add the family members and his/her relationship with that member.

For Example:

In a family Father is one of the member and his wife is another member and they have children. But the number of children in each family are different(eg only one son/only one daughter/one son one daughter and so on). Therefore number of children decided at run time.

I have one tables:

- **Members tables**: In which details of all the members such as member_reference_number, name, address, phone number etc. are to be store. member_reference_number is a primary key which identifies the unique member from database. This table is for any member(father, mother,son, daughter etc).

I want to use that member_reference_number to show the relationship.

Comment: AHA!! Assignment!!Let's get it done on SO!

Comment: [tag:java], [tag:c++], [tag:c] or [tag:data_structures]?

Comment: @Gaurav What have `you` tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read this [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for information on how use SO and how to post questions. Then when you encounter a specific problem and post a question please include a [Short Self Contained Correct/Compilable Example - SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object oriented + Inheritence can help you. I think you mean this structure:

```
class Person
{};

class Father : public Person
{};

class Mother : public Person
{};

class Child : public Father, public Mother
{};

class Son : public Child
{};

class Daughter: public Child
{};

class Family
{
  Father father;
  Mother mother;
  std::vector<Child> children;
};
```

```
              +------------------+               
              |       Person     |               
              +------------------+               
                ^             ^                  
                |             |                  
                |             |                  
                \             \                  
 +------------------+      +------------------+  
 |     Father       |      |     Mother       |  
 +------------------+      +------------------+  
                 ^            ^                  
                 |            |                  
                 |            |                  
                 |            |                  
                 \            \                  
              +------------------+               
              |     Child        |               
              +------------------+               
                 ^           ^                   
                 |           |                   
                 |           |                   
                 \           \                   
 +------------------+      +------------------+  
 |     Son          |      |    Daughter      |  
 +------------------+      +------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to use member_reference_number to show the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can have tree with FamilyTreeNode.

where FamilyTreeNode (structure) can have

-> Male               -- `String`

-> Female             -- `String`

-> NumberOfChildern   -- `int`

-> Children           -- array of FamilyTreeNodes (dynamic array).

Here if anyone is not married then make the opp sex to null.